# Implementing a function using lambda or comprehension list

Tags: python

stack!

I've the following piece of code. As you can the only piece changes is Index.

```py
    amount = response.json()['txrefs'][0]['tx_hash'] 
    amount = response.json()['txrefs'][1]['tx_hash']
    amount = response.json()['txrefs'][2]['tx_hash']
    amount = response.json()['txrefs'][3]['tx_hash']
```

I have tried to implement it using comprehension list. But still without success.
How is it possible to iterate with lambda or comprehension list?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. a `lambda` expression is for creating anonymous functions... Why would you want to use a `lambda` to begin with? A list comprehension is for *creating lists*, and that isn't what you are doing here... you probably just want a for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehension syntax you might be thinking of would be something like:

```
amounts = [txref['tx_hash'] for txref in response.json()['txrefs']]
```

Note that this gives you a list of all the `tx_hash` values rather than just overwriting the same one over and over.

If you wanted to define a function to get an arbitrary value to avoid the duplication, that might be:

```
get_txhash = lambda i: response.json()['txrefs'][i]['tx_hash']
```

But there's no reason to use a `lambda` instead of a `def` here:

```
def get_txhash(i):
    return response.json()['txrefs'][i]['tx_hash']
```

Comment: Not only is there no reason to use a lambda expression here, it is explicitely against PEP8 style guidelines to assign the result of a lambda to a name (the only *point* of a lambda expression is to create an anonymous function)